# Possible Chrome App console.log bug, or am I missing something?

Tags: google-chrome-app, console.log

The following is a screen shot from the console log of a Chrome App that makes no sense to me:

[image]

The first line shows that the p_adview property is null and p_bVoid is true (not what I expect). I expand this line, and it seems to show that p_adview is an instance of AdView, and p_bVoid is false (exactly as expected).

What am I missing? Shouldn't these be the same?

When I run the program, it acts as if p_bVoid is true - not what I expect. I am trying to debug this problem, but the console log has me baffled.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question - the stuff in the log in italics is the correct, current value. The stuff below "is captured upon first expansion", i.e., is not correct. There is a little icon at the end of the line in italics which you can hover over to see this message. I find this more than a bit obscure, but at least I can stop banging my head against the wall for now.